# c# Auto populate result of a textboxt.Text from database, base on 2 different combo box

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio

```
namespace Training
{
public partial class AddingNewData : Form
{
    public AddingNewData()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        fillcombo1();
        fillcombo2();
        autopopulatedays();
}

string original_city, destination_city;

void fillcombo1()
{
    string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
    string Query = "SELECT * FROM itemdelivery.fee GROUP BY orig_city;";
    MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
    MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
    MySqlDataReader myReader;

    try
    {
        conDataBase.Open();
        myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            string storig = myReader.GetString("orig_city");
            comboBox1.Items.Add(storig);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

void fillcombo2()
{
    string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
    string Query = "SELECT * FROM itemdelivery.fee GROUP BY dest_city;";
    MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
    MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
    MySqlDataReader myReader;

    try
    {
        conDataBase.Open();
        myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            string stdest = myReader.GetString("dest_city");
            comboBox2.Items.Add(stdest);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    original_city = comboBox1.Text;
}

private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    destination_city = comboBox2.Text;
}

private void txt_deliverytime_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

void autopopulatedays()
{
    string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
    string Query = "SELECT `del_time` FROM `itemdelivery.fee` WHERE `orig_city` = @oc AND `dest_city`= @dc";
    MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
    MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);

    try
    {
        conDataBase.Open();
        cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oc", original_city);
        cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dc", destination_city);

        object result = cmdDataBase.ExecuteScalar();
        if (result != null)
            txt_deliverytime.Text = result.ToString();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
  }
}
}
```

So, I have 2 combo boxes,  After selecting 2 of them, I put the values in `original_city` and `destination_city` as `string`, using `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` and `comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged`.

Then on method `autopopulatedays()`, I tried to auto-populate the `txt_deliverytime.Text` with a single integer value  by matching the value of `original_city` and `destination_city` on the database using
that query.

But, so why I failed? The only error I got is `"No database selected"` which is weird for me, and when I select 2 combo box choices, the
`txt_deliverytime.Text` doesn't get auto-populated.

========================================================================

```
// UPDATE VERSION
// Connected to database, and ignoring the code before(above),
// This code only meant to auto-populate txt_deliverytime.Text when
// combobox1.selectitem and combobox2.selectitem
// Why it's still wrong?.



    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        original_city = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

    }

    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        destination_city = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();

    // if the combobox1 is not empty and combobox2 is also not empty, then run this code
        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() != null)
        {

            string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
            string Query = "SELECT del_time FROM itemdelivery.fee WHERE orig_city='" + original_city + "' AND dest_city='" + destination_city + "';";
             // if I run this query on MySQL, it will show only a column name del_time with only a single row, 
             // thus only show a value, I want to get that value to txt_deliverytime.Text
             MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
             MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
            conDataBase.Open();

            string getValue = cmdDataBase.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            if (getValue != null)
            {
                txt_deliverytime.Text = getValue.ToString();
        // meant to change it here, but seems not successful
            }
            conDataBase.Close();

        }
    }
```

Comment: you need to provide database name either in the connection string or in the query

Comment: If I delete the autopopulatedays method, I would not get the "No database selected" error.
So @viveknuna , can you tell me how to do your suggestion? (aka the code)

Comment: I just update my post, there is no problem with connection anymore, It's fine. Please help me correct the code on the update version.

Comment: has you debugged `comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(...)`? have `original_city` and `destination_city` the correct value?

Comment: still cannot see `Database=sth` in your connection string

Comment: I did debug that, and they got the correct value,
I believe that "datasource=localhost;" is the database you're looking for, that is what it's like from youtube tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

First use a valid `ConnectionString`:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Port=1234;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;
```

Pwd=myPassword;

Then I suppose this is not your actual code, because there is a missing curly bracket

```
public partial class AddingNewData : Form
{
    public AddingNewData()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        fillcombo1();
        fillcombo2();
        autopopulatedays();
}
```

And finally you should `autopopulatedays' when comboBox1 or comboBox2 selected item change, not only when you fill the combos.

Comment: I just update my post, there is no problem with connection anymore, It's fine. Please help me correct the code on the update version.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the code above into the code like this below =

```
namespace Training
{
    public partial class AddingNewData : Form
    {
        public AddingNewData()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            fillcombo1();
            fillcombo2();
    }

    string original_city, destination_city;

void fillcombo1()
{
    string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
    string Query = "SELECT * FROM itemdelivery.fee GROUP BY orig_city;";
    MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
    MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
    MySqlDataReader myReader;

    try
    {
        conDataBase.Open();
        myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            string storig = myReader.GetString("orig_city");
            comboBox1.Items.Add(storig);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

void fillcombo2()
{
    // EMPTY
}

// just some improvement on query
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    original_city = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

    string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
    string Query = "SELECT DISTINCT dest_city FROM itemdelivery.fee WHERE orig_city = '" + original_city + "' GROUP BY destination_city ;";
    MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
    MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
    MySqlDataReader myReader;

    try
    {
        conDataBase.Open();
        myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            string stdest = myReader.GetString("dest_city");
            comboBox2.Items.Add(stdest);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

// this is where I solved the problem
private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    destination_city = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();

    string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
    string Query = "SELECT del_time FROM itemdelivery.fee WHERE orig_city ='" + original_city + "' AND dest_city ='" + destination_city + "';";
    MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
    MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);

        try
        {
            conDataBase.Open();

            var result = cmdDataBase.ExecuteScalar();
                if (result != null)
                {
                    txt_deliverytime.Text = result.ToString();
                }

            conDataBase.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
}

private void txt_deliverytime_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

}